# AVPlayer "freezes" the app at the start of buffering an audio stream

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, dropbox, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I am using a subclass of `AVQueuePlayer` and when I add new `AVPlayerItem` with a streaming URL the app freezes for about a second or two. By freezing I mean that it doesn't respond to touches on the UI. Also, if I have a song playing already and then add another one to the queue, `AVQueuePlayer` automatically starts preloading the song while it is still streaming the first one. This makes the app not respond to touches on the UI for two seconds just like when adding the first song but the song is still playing. So that means `AVQueuePlayer` is doing something in main thread that is causing the apparent "freeze".

I am using `insertItem:afterItem:` to add my `AVPlayerItem`. I tested and made sure that this was the method that was causing the delay. Maybe it could be something that `AVPlayerItem` does when it gets activated by `AVQueuePlayer` at the moment of adding it to the queue.

Must point out that I am using the Dropbox API v1 beta to get the streaming URL by using this method call:

```
[[self restClient] loadStreamableURLForFile:metadata.path];
```

Then when I receive the stream URL I send it to `AVQueuePlayer` as follows:

```
[self.player insertItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url] afterItem:nil];
```

So my question is: How do I avoid this?
Should I do the preloading of an audio stream on my own without the help of `AVPlayer`? If so, how do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Will this happen even if it is called on a different thread? Have you tried detaching and calling it there?

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Then later I read the documentation and turns out that AVPlayer methods should always be called on the main thread.

Comment: You could try hanging onto the AVPlayerItem until it's status is AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay. For instance, check several times a second to see if it's ready to play, then when it is add it to the queue. Perhaps insertItem is waiting synchronously for the AVPlayerItem to be ready.

Comment: That still doesn't mean that it won't freeze between songs. I don't want it to ever freeze.

Comment: same problem to me. I have to use AVPlayer to instead.

Answer (score 82):

Don't use `playerItemWithURL` it's sync.
When you receive the response with the url try this:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
NSArray *keys = @[@"playable"];

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() {
    [self.player insertItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset] afterItem:nil];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this tidbit Gigi. More people should be reading this answer.

Comment: It's very important to note that the completionHandler block is not invoked in the main thread (or at least is not guaranteed to), then you should use a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }) inside of it.

Comment: I added @"tracks" and @"duration" to 'keys' array to solve similar issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this answer, it's helped me. But The problem is persistent after the insertion of some items (only for sounds and not movies). Those are playing but if their are not completely loaded, the main thread is also blocked....

Comment: How can I Achieve this in AVPlayer. Actually, I'm not using AVQUEUEPLAYER. Can you give me any idea to achieve :) @Gigisommo

Comment: If just using AVPlayer you can follow this same approach but instead of "insertItem" use "replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem". (And to get the asset from an AVPlayerItem use "item.asset".)

Comment: you are a god amongst men.

Comment: What are all the possible keys?

Comment: @AzizJaved From Apple documentation: 'The keys are the property names of a class that adopts the protocol.'. In this case AVURLAsset is the class that implement the AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading protocol. You can find its property here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset?language=objc

Answer (score 24):

Bump, since this is a highly rated question and similar questions online either has outdated answers or aren't great. The whole idea is pretty straight forward with `AVKit` and `AVFoundation`, which means no more depending on third party libraries. The only issue is that it took some tinkering around and put the pieces together.

`AVFoundation`'s `Player()` initialization with `url` is apparently not thread safe, or rather it's not meant to be. Which means, no matter how you initialize it in a background thread the player attributes are going to be loaded in the main queue causing freezes in the UI especially in `UITableView`s and `UICollectionViews`. To solve this issue Apple provided `AVAsset` which takes a URL and assists in loading the media attributes like track, playback, duration etc. and can do so asynchronously, with a best part being that this loading process is cancellable (unlike other Dispatch queue background threads where ending a task may not be that straight forward). This means, there is no need to worry about lingering zombie threads in the background as you scroll fast on a table view or collection view, ultimately piling up on the memory with a whole bunch of unused objects. This `cancellable` feature is great, and allows us to cancel any lingering `AVAsset` async load if it is in progress but only during cell dequeue. The async loading process can be invoked by the `loadValuesAsynchronously` method, and can be cancelled (at will) at any later time (if still in progress).

Don't forget to exception handle properly using the results of `loadValuesAsynchronously`. In **Swift (3/4)**, here's how you would would load a video asynchronously and handle situations if the async process fails (due to slow networks, etc.)-

**TL;DR**

### TO PLAY A VIDEO

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: self.YOUR_URL_STRING))
let keys: [String] = ["playable"]
var player: AVPlayer!                

asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
     var error: NSError? = nil
     let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
     switch status {
        case .loaded:
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
               let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
               self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
               let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
               playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
               playerLayer.frame = self.YOUR_VIDEOS_UIVIEW.bounds
               self.YOUR_VIDEOS_UIVIEW.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
               self.player.isMuted = true
               self.player.play()
            }
            break
        case .failed:
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 //do something, show alert, put a placeholder image etc.
            }
            break
         case .cancelled:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //do something, show alert, put a placeholder image etc.
            }
            break
         default:
            break
   }
})
```

**NOTE**:

Based on what your app wants to achieve you may still have to do some amount of tinkering to tune it to get smoother scroll in a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. You may also need to implement some amount of KVO on the `AVPlayerItem` properties for it to work and there's plenty of posts here in SO that discuss `AVPlayerItem` KVOs in detail.

---

### TO LOOP THROUGH ASSETS (video loops/GIFs)

To loop a video, you can use the same method above and introducing `AVPlayerLooper`. Here's a sample code to loop a video (or perhaps a short video in GIF style). **Note** the use of `duration` key which is required for our video loop.

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: self.YOUR_URL_STRING))
let keys: [String] = ["playable","duration"]
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper!

asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
     var error: NSError? = nil
     let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &error)
     switch status {
        case .loaded:
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                 self.player = AVQueuePlayer()
                 let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)

                 //define Timerange for the loop using asset.duration
                 let duration = playerItem.asset.duration
                 let start = CMTime(seconds: duration.seconds * 0, preferredTimescale: duration.timescale)
                 let end = CMTime(seconds: duration.seconds * 1, preferredTimescale: duration.timescale)
                 let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: start, end: end)

                 self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.player as! AVQueuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem, timeRange: timeRange)
                 playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                 playerLayer.frame = self.YOUR_VIDEOS_UIVIEW.bounds
               self.YOUR_VIDEOS_UIVIEW.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                 self.player.isMuted = true
                 self.player.play()
            }
            break
        case .failed:
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 //do something, show alert, put a placeholder image etc.
            }
            break
         case .cancelled:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //do something, show alert, put a placeholder image etc.
            }
            break
         default:
            break
   }
})
```

**EDIT** : As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper/1643626-initwithplayer), `AVPlayerLooper` requires the `duration` property of the asset to be fully loaded in order to be able to loop through videos. Also, the `timeRange: timeRange` with the start and end timerange in the `AVPlayerLooper` initialization is really optional if you want an infinite loop. I have also realized since I posted this answer that `AVPlayerLooper` is only about 70-80% accurate in looping videos, especially if your `AVAsset` needs to stream the video from a URL. In order to solve this issue there is a totally different (yet simple) approach to loop a video-

```
//this will loop the video since this is a Gif
  let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
  self.timeObserverToken = self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in
                            if let totalDuration = self.player?.currentItem?.duration{
                                if progressTime == totalDuration{
                                    self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
                                    self.player?.play()
                                }
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: I translated to code to Objective-c and it is still not working. The code freezes up the main thread.

Answer (score 8):

Gigisommo's answer for **Swift 3** including the feedback from the comments:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let keys: [String] = ["playable"]

asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys) { 

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            self.playerCtrl.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 15+, async await

```swift
Task {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let playable = try await asset.load(.isPlayable)
    if playable {
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: .init(asset: asset))
        player.play()
    }
}
```