# Video stucks/delayed while getting start using AVPlayer, in iPad pro only

Tags: objective-c, ipad, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

Am using AVPlayer to play video. Video playing without any problem except iPad Pro. In iPad pro its getting stuck or delayed to start.

```
avPlayerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:fileURL];
player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
avPlayerViewController.player = player;
[avPlayerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, biManager.screenSize.width, biManager.screenSize.height)];
[self.view addSubview:avPlayerViewController.view];
avPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false ;
[player play];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `initWithURL` is a sync call and may stop your UI. I went around it in my code by saving the video to a temp file and start the play only when the file was downloaded. Alternatively, you can try `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:` as suggested  [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701212/avplayer-freezes-the-app-at-the-start-of-buffering-an-audio-stream). Also, there should be a way to stream videos with buffering. May be with third party's API like AFNetworking?